# Is there any solution for not prompting user to signin again in single signon authentication addin?

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, dynamics-crm, outlook-addin

I have created single signon authentication addin connecting to dynamics 365 - where i have added the function "getaccesstoken" in ssoauth-helper.js file and accessing it in taskpane.js, but it is not getting stored and asking user to signin again when the addin is refreshed or opened.

Below is the function:

```
export async function getAccessToken(authorization, scope) {
  if (accessTokenCache && accessTokenCache.expiresAt > new Date()) {
    // The cached access token is still valid, so return it
    return accessTokenCache.accessToken;
  } else {
    if (!authorization) {
      let error = new Error("No Authorization header was found.");
      return Promise.reject(error);
    } else {
      const scopeName = scope; //process.env.SCOPE || "User.Read";
      const [, /* schema */ assertion] = authorization.split(" ");
      const tokenScopes = jwt.decode(assertion).scp.split(" ");
      const accessAsUserScope = tokenScopes.find((scope) => scope === "access_as_user");
      if (!accessAsUserScope) {
        throw new Error("Missing access_as_user");
      }

      const formParams = {
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        assertion: assertion,
        requested_token_use: "on_behalf_of",
        scope: [scopeName].join(" "),
      };

      const stsDomain = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
      const tenant = "common";
      const tokenURLSegment = "oauth2/v2.0/token";
      const encodedForm = form(formParams);

      let tokenResponse = await fetch(`${stsDomain}/${tenant}/${tokenURLSegment}`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: encodedForm,
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
      });

      let json = await tokenResponse.json();

      // Check if the access token is expired and refresh it with the refresh token if necessary
      if (json.error && json.error === "invalid_grant") {
        const refreshToken = json.refresh_token;
        const refreshParams = {
          client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
          grant_type: "refresh_token",
          refresh_token: refreshToken,
          scope: [scopeName].join(" "),`your text`
        };

        const refreshEncodedForm = form(refreshParams);

        tokenResponse = await fetch(`${stsDomain}/${tenant}/${tokenURLSegment}`, {
          method: "POST",
          body: refreshEncodedForm,
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
        });

        json = await tokenResponse.json();
      }

      // Store the access token and its expiry time in the cache
      accessTokenCache = {
        accessToken: json.access_token,
        expiresAt: new Date(Date.now() + json.expires_in * 1000),
      };

      return json.access_token;
    }
  }
}
```

Accessing the above function results in temporary solution, but once the laptop is shut down or when we run the addin, it just asks me to signin again which i dont want.
What solution can be applied or the changes that can work?